# Pass ng-repeat table column values to an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Upon searching in the form for an artist or song, a table of songs is returned with column titles that are descriptions of info associated with the songs. My goal is to get only "Track Id" column values to be sent to an array for later use. For example, if five songs are returned and the individual track ids are 111, 222, 333, 444, and 555, then I want an array, say "trackids" to be trackids=[111, 222, 333, 444, and 555]. There are two approaches I am considering; doing something like get getelementbyId/tag for the specific column or alternatively having the song.trackId data be sent directly to the "trackids" array. Here is the code:

```
<body>

  <div ng-controller="iTunesController">
 {{ error }}
    <form name="search" ng-submit="searchiTunes(artist)">
      <input type="search" required placeholder="Artist or Song" ng-model="artist" />
      <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
<div class="element"></div>
    <table id="SongInfo" ng-show="songs">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Album Artwork</th>
          <th>Track</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
          <th></th>
          <th>Track Id</th>
          <th>Preview</th>
          <th>Track Info</th>
          <th>Track Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="song in songs">
          <td><img ng-src="{{song.artworkUrl60}}" alt="{{song.collectionName}}" />
          </td>
          <td>{{song.trackName}}</td>
          <td>{{song.artistName}}</td>
          <td>
            <button ng-click="handleAdd(song)">Add Track</button>
          </td>
          <td>{{song.trackId}}</td>
          <td><a href="{{song.previewUrl}}">Play</a></td>
          <td><a href="{{song.trackViewUrl}}">View Track Info</a></td>
          <td>{{song.trackPrice}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

itunes_controller.js

```
(function() {

  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('iTunesController', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.searchiTunes = function(artist) {
        $http.jsonp('http://itunes.apple.com/search', {
          params: {
            'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK',
            'term': artist,
            limit: 5,
          }
        }).then(onSearchComplete, onError)
      }
var onSearchComplete = function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data
        $scope.songs = response.data.results
      }

      var onError = function(reason) {
        $scope.error = reason
      }

    });


}())
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just getting the IDs when the data is first returned?

```
var onSearchComplete = function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data
        $scope.songs = response.data.results
        $scope.trackIds = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.songs, function(song) {
            $scope.trackIds.push(song.trackId)
        }) // trackIds are now stored in $scope.trackIds
      }
```